# Cómo implementar este script en medio de un DIV

Tags: javascript, php

solicito una guía para cambiar implementar este script en html directamente.
Lo que busco es poner el script directamente en el HTML. y que me muestre las estrellas, aplicando la clase star-light y muestre las estrellas.

```js
for(var star = 1; star <= 5; star++)
                        {
                            var class_name = '';

                            if(data.review_data[count].rating >= star)
                            {
                                class_name = 'text-warning';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                class_name = 'star-light';
                            }

                            html += '<i class="fas fa-star '+class_name+' mr-1"></i>';
                        }
```

Esto es lo que he intentado para mostrar el valor de la variable data.review_data[count].rating ha sido esto pero no me funciona.

```html
<div class="card-body">
<script>

for(var star = 1; star <= 5; star++)
                        {
                            var class_name = '';

                            if(data.review_data[count].rating >= star)
                            {
                                class_name = 'text-warning';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                class_name = 'star-light';
                            }

                            html += '<i class="fas fa-star '+class_name+' mr-1"></i>';
                        }



</script>
</div>
```

Continuo tratando de solucionar este detalle y tengo lo siguiente pero tampoco me funciona

```js
<script>
function user_rating() {
for(var star = 1; star <= 5; star++) {
  var class_name = '';
  if(data.review_data[count].rating >= star) {
    class_name = 'text-warning';
  } else {
    class_name = 'star-light';
  }
  html += '<i class="fas fa-star ' + class_name + ' mr-1"></i>';
                                }
                                document.getElementById('user_rating').innerHTML = user_rating()                    
                        };
          
</script>
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div id"resultado"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Simple y sencillamente, no puedes. El elemento [<script>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) puede tener padres de tipo [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) o [metadata content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#metadata_content). `<div>` no es ninguno de los dos.

Comment: Suena a un problema de tipo [X -> Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), donde tienes un problema 'X' y creas una solución 'Y'. Pero tu solución 'Y' tiene su propio problema y lo quieres resolver. Lo que no sabes es que tu solución 'Y' en realidad no es una solución para tu problema 'X', y ya has perdido un montón de tiempo en solucionar 'Y', que podrías usar para solucionar 'X'. Entonces, **qué es lo que en realidad quieres lograr?**

Comment: Dentro de un div no se puede. Pero dijiste en el HTML, entonces si se puede: dentro de la etiqueta `body`, al final de todos. Ahí se puede insertar el script `<script></script>`

Comment: Ya la he colocado al final del body, pero no sé como llamarla para que muestre en el div

Comment: De dónde viene `user_rating()` ? Y también de dónde viene `data.review_data[count].rating` ? Porque estos son los problemas que no se puede mostrar en el HTML. O tal vez falta algo de código js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por fin logré resolver mi problema, lo único que debía hacer era transformar el script a código php y me quedó de esta manera:

```php
<div class="card-header">Review by <b><?php echo $rws['user_name']?></b>
    <div class="alignright">
        <?php 
        
        for($star = 1; $star <= 5; $star++) {
                $class_name = '';
        if($rws['user_rating'] >= $star) {
        $class_name = 'text-warning';
        } else {
        $class_name = 'star-light';
        }
        echo  '<i class="fas fa-star ' . $class_name .' mr-1"></i>';
        }
        ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Con esto, se revisa el valor del user_rating en la base e datos y dependiendo del número pinta las estrellas usando la clase text-warning, si hay por ejemplo una calificación de 4 estrellas, entonces pinta 1 con la clase star-light.

es todo mil gracias a quienes apoyaron.

Answer (score 1):

Realice una demostración de cómo mostrar tu contenido en el DOM (HTML).

La función `user_rating()` es llamado desde otra parte, pero en esta demo se auto llama al final, para que funcione.

En el `if` comenté para que funcione la demo Tu vuelve a descomentar.

En el `if` y `else` agregué el contenido para mostrar en el DOM mediante backtik (comilla simple invertida). O no se verá. En cada unas de ellas puedes modificar el estilo de la etiqueta `<i>` (o insertar cualquier HTML).

Espero que esto te ayude a mejorar

```js
function user_rating() { 
 
 for(var star = 1; star <= 5; star++) { 
  
  var html = '';
  
  if( /* data.review_data[count].rating >= */ star) { 
   
   html += `
   <i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i> 
   <h1>Estoy en el IF</h1>
   `; 

  } else {
   
   html += `
   <i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i> 
   `; 
   
  } 
  
 }; 
  
 // se muestra el html en #resultado
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = html;   

};

// si esta función no es llamada en otro lado, se cierra aquí 
// Puedes quitar esto luego
user_rating();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div class="card-body"> 
   
   <div id="resultado">a</div> 
   
  </div>
  
  <!-- enlazar archivo .js al final de body (aquí) -->
  <script src=""></script>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```